# TypeScript import statement cannot find Firebase module in Expo project

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm starting a brand new Expo project and following all docs as published on August 28, 2021. The import statement specified by the Firebase docs does not work. Here are the steps to reproduce.

```
expo init firebase-demo
```

Select `blank (TypeScript)` and hit enter.

```
cd firebase-demo
expo install firebase
```

Add this line to App.tsx, as the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?authuser=0#web-version-9) say:

```js
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

And you get this error: Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'getAuth'.

A clue as to what's going wrong is that in VS Code, if I command-click on `"firebase/auth"` it opens node_modules/firebase/empty-import.d.ts whose entire content is:

```js
declare namespace empty {}
export = empty;
```

There is a node_modules/firebase/auth directory. Why isn't the import statement finding that?

Here's my tsconfig.json, which I have not modified from what expo init created:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. My solution is:

add: `"exclude": ["node_modules", "node_modules/**/*"]`
to your `jsconfig.json`
and then `Ctrl+Shift+P -> Reload window`

Another solution I ran into:

do the same, but delete `node_modules` folder from your project before editing `jsconfig.json` and run `npm install` right after `Ctrl+Shift+P -> Reload Window`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading firebase to 9.0.0. The problem seems to be caused by the fact that `expo install firebase` installed quite an old version - 8.2.3, from 7 months ago. The current version is 9.0.0, and the current documentation is presumably for that. I'm going to proceed with caution because 9.0.0 isn't certified for use with Expo. (I guess another possible solution would be to find the documentation for 8.2.3).